# How to conditionally draw parts of a MetaPost drawing in ConTeXt?

Tags: conditionals, context, metapost

The basis of my problem is I am making a 14x14 crossword puzzle, I have the data for each of the 196 cells from an outside document, but need only the cells with text inside to have borders.

I tried using MetaPost to solve this. For simplicity, I've reduced the code to just a 14x1 grid example here.

I created an outside script which gives me all of the values that should go inside the grid. E.g., if the first row has "cat" across, then it gives this:

```
\setvalue{1}{c}
\setvalue{2}{a}
\setvalue{3}{t}
\setvalue{4}{}
\setvalue{5}{}
\setvalue{6}{}
\setvalue{7}{}
\setvalue{8}{}
\setvalue{9}{}
\setvalue{10}{}
\setvalue{11}{}
\setvalue{12}{}
\setvalue{13}{}
\setvalue{14}{}
```

The full 14x14 example has 196 such variables, but place in another file by a script, so they aren't unwieldy.

I used MetaPost to create many boxes, rather than tables, as I could find no clean way to add the subscript text to the corner of a cell in a table without it pushing the letter in that cell to the right.

Here is the minimal working example of the solution page is this:

```
\setvalue{1}{c}
\setvalue{2}{a}
\setvalue{3}{t}
\setvalue{4}{}
\setvalue{5}{}
\setvalue{6}{}
\setvalue{7}{}
\setvalue{8}{}
\setvalue{9}{}
\setvalue{10}{}
\setvalue{11}{}
\setvalue{12}{}
\setvalue{13}{}
\setvalue{14}{}

\define\crosswordsolution{%
    \scale[width=\textwidth]{%
        \startMPcode
            draw (0,0)--(100,0)--(100,100)--(0,100)--(0,0);
            draw (100,0)--(200,0)--(200,100)--(100,100)--(100,0);
            draw (200,0)--(300,0)--(300,100)--(200,100)--(200,0);
            draw (300,0)--(400,0)--(400,100)--(300,100)--(300,0);
            draw (400,0)--(500,0)--(500,100)--(400,100)--(400,0);
            draw (500,0)--(600,0)--(600,100)--(500,100)--(500,0);
            draw (600,0)--(700,0)--(700,100)--(600,100)--(600,0);
            draw (700,0)--(800,0)--(800,100)--(700,100)--(700,0);
            draw (800,0)--(900,0)--(900,100)--(800,100)--(800,0);
            draw (900,0)--(1000,0)--(1000,100)--(900,100)--(900,0);
            draw (1000,0)--(1100,0)--(1100,100)--(1000,100)--(1000,0);
            draw (1100,0)--(1200,0)--(1200,100)--(1100,100)--(1100,0);
            draw (1200,0)--(1300,0)--(1300,100)--(1200,100)--(1200,0);
            draw (1300,0)--(1400,0)--(1400,100)--(1300,100)--(1300,0);

            label("\getvalue{1}", (50,50));
            label("\getvalue{2}", (150,50));
            label("\getvalue{3}", (250,50));
            label("\getvalue{4}", (350,50));
            label("\getvalue{5}", (450,50));
            label("\getvalue{6}", (550,50));
            label("\getvalue{7}", (650,50));
            label("\getvalue{8}", (750,50));
            label("\getvalue{9}", (850,50));
            label("\getvalue{10}", (950,50));
            label("\getvalue{11}", (1050,50));
            label("\getvalue{12}", (1150,50));
            label("\getvalue{13}", (1250,50));
            label("\getvalue{14}", (1350,50));
            label("1", (25,75));
        \stopMPcode
    }%
}%

\starttext
    \crosswordsolution
\stoptext
```

The problem I have is that I need only those boxes with a letter inside to be drawn. The empty boxes needn't be drawn at all. In other words, only the boxes containing the letters in C-A-T need to be drawn, the others are invisible.

I tried using simple TeX conditionals inside MetaPost, checking if the variable is empty, but the code came up with errors, so I suspect MetaPost can't have TeX or ConTeXt code inside `\startMPcode` and `\endMPcode`.

Is there some way to create conditions that allows specific boxes to be drawn only if the matching variable has text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find it easier to use Metapost logical structures.  Here is some plain MP, that does what (I think) you want:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

    string cell[];
    cell1 := "C";
    cell2 := "A";
    cell3 := "T";
    cell4 := "";
    cell5 := "S";
    cell6 := "A";
    cell7 := "T";
    cell8 := "";
    cell9 := "";
    cell10 := "";
    cell11 := "H";
    cell12 := "E";
    cell13 := "R";
    cell14 := "E";

    path box;
    box = unitsquare shifted -(1/2, 1/2) scaled 10;

    numeric x, y;
    y = 5;
    x = 5;
    for i=1 upto 14:
        if cell[i] <> "": 
            label(cell[i], (x, y));
            draw box shifted (x, y);
        fi
        x := x + 10; 
    endfor

endfig;
end.
```

If you compile this with plain `mpost` you should get this:

[image]

Everything that works in plain Metapost between `beginfig` and `endfig` should work without change between `\startMPcode` and `\stopMPcode` in Context.

You could adapt this to your values by assigning `cell1 := "\getvalue{1}"` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use TeX conditionals in MetaPost but they have to be fully-expandable and avoid the “incomplete if” problem.  The resulting code is not pretty and Toby's answer is clearly preferable.

```
\setvalue{1}{c}
\setvalue{2}{a}
\setvalue{3}{t}
\setvalue{4}{}
\setvalue{5}{}
\setvalue{6}{}
\setvalue{7}{}
\setvalue{8}{}
\setvalue{9}{}
\setvalue{10}{}
\setvalue{11}{}
\setvalue{12}{}
\setvalue{13}{}
\setvalue{14}{}

% \getvalue only yields its value after two expansion steps,
% therefore we need to use \doubleexpandafter
\def\expdoifvalue#1%
    {\doubleexpandafter\ifx\getvalue{#1}\empty
         \expandafter\gobbleoneargument
     \else
         \expandafter\firstofoneargument
     \fi}

\define\crosswordsolution{%
    \scale[width=\textwidth]{%
        \startMPcode
            \expdoifvalue{1}{
                draw (0,0)--(100,0)--(100,100)--(0,100)--(0,0);
                label("\getvalue{1}", (50,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{2}{
                draw (100,0)--(200,0)--(200,100)--(100,100)--(100,0);
                label("\getvalue{2}", (150,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{3}{
                draw (200,0)--(300,0)--(300,100)--(200,100)--(200,0);
                label("\getvalue{3}", (250,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{4}{
                draw (300,0)--(400,0)--(400,100)--(300,100)--(300,0);
                label("\getvalue{4}", (350,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{5}{
                draw (400,0)--(500,0)--(500,100)--(400,100)--(400,0);
                label("\getvalue{5}", (450,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{6}{
                draw (500,0)--(600,0)--(600,100)--(500,100)--(500,0);
                label("\getvalue{6}", (550,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{7}{
                draw (600,0)--(700,0)--(700,100)--(600,100)--(600,0);
                label("\getvalue{7}", (650,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{8}{
                draw (700,0)--(800,0)--(800,100)--(700,100)--(700,0);
                label("\getvalue{8}", (750,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{9}{
                draw (800,0)--(900,0)--(900,100)--(800,100)--(800,0);
                label("\getvalue{9}", (850,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{10}{
                draw (900,0)--(1000,0)--(1000,100)--(900,100)--(900,0);
                label("\getvalue{10}", (950,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{11}{
                draw (1000,0)--(1100,0)--(1100,100)--(1000,100)--(1000,0);
                label("\getvalue{11}", (1050,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{12}{
                draw (1100,0)--(1200,0)--(1200,100)--(1100,100)--(1100,0);
                label("\getvalue{12}", (1150,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{13}{
                draw (1200,0)--(1300,0)--(1300,100)--(1200,100)--(1200,0);
                label("\getvalue{13}", (1250,50));
            }
            \expdoifvalue{14}{
                draw (1300,0)--(1400,0)--(1400,100)--(1300,100)--(1300,0);
                label("\getvalue{14}", (1350,50));
            }

            label("1", (25,75));
        \stopMPcode
    }%
}%

\starttext
    \crosswordsolution
\stoptext
```

Instead of implementing `\expdoifvalue{1}{...}` you could also use the builtin `\expdoifnot{\getvalue{1}}{}{...}`.  However, `\expdoifnot` performs a full expansion which might not always be desirable.